# Remove data and timestamp in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

A function call in nodejs returns a JSON object which is of below format:

```
**2018-01-24T19:03:37.736Z 47306e51-0139-11e8-9cbb-2d7164fff26e**

{
  GroupId: "sg-sdfdg",
  GroupName: "launch-wizard-2",
  IpPermissions: [
    {
      IpProtocol: "-1",
      IpRanges: [  
        {
          CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
        } 
      ]
    }
  ] 
}
```

Timestamp gets embedded in the array object which is causing some issue while passing this object as input to another function. I want to remove the timestamp from this output.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Is this supposed to be a JSON string? If so, it is not valid. Before you post something as JSON you should check that it is valid: https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the actual JSON, you can use JS:

```
.replace(/ *\*[^)]*\* */g, "");
```

This will remove everything between the stars('*').